# Install NuGet package without adding any references in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

I need to create a NuGet package with DLLs which should not be directly referenced in Visual Studio. The idea is for them to end up in some kind of `bin` folder during build, as they will be implicitly called by other assemblies during runtime.

The best solution I could find is to add into the package a DLL which I planned to reference anyway, so that that's referenced and the other DLLs are not ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#Specifying_Explicit_Assembly_References)):

```
<references>
    <reference file="OnlyTheFileIWantReferenced.dll" />
</references>
```

But ideally I'd like to find a way to do this without the workaround above, I'm sure there's bound to be some kind of directive in the `.nuspec` file I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Install NuGet package without adding any references in Visual Studio

To accomplish this, you can target the dll files to the `tools` folder instead of `lib` folder in the `.nupsec` file:

```
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\Unreference.dll" target="Tools\Unreference.dll" />
  </files>
```

Following is my `.nuspec` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyModels</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>Tester</authors>
    <owners>Tester</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package description</description>
    <releaseNotes>Summary of changes made in this release of the package.</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2018</copyright>
    <tags>Tag1 Tag2</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.dll" target="lib\Net45" />
    <file src="bin\Debug\Unreference.dll" target="Tools\Unreference.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

After pack this `.nuspec`, we will get the nuget package:

[image]

Then install this package to the project, the `MyModels.dll` will be added to the Reference, but `Unreference.dll` will not, this dll file exists in the packages folder:`packages\MyModels.1.0.0\Tools`, where you can implicitly called or you can copy it to some kind of `bin` folder by build event or msbuild copy task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Leo, does this solution requiring referencing at least one file? To make it clearer, will this work if I have a NuGet package with nothing referenced?

Comment: @globetrotter, `will this work if I have a NuGet package with nothing referenced?`--Yes, It still work. Just remove the this line `<file src="bin\Debug\MyModels.dll" target="lib\Net45" />` in the .nuspec file.

Comment: thanks @Leo, I've upvoted and will mark as answer as soon as I test it.

Comment: @globetrotter, Is it helpful for you? Any update about this issue?

Comment: Hey everybody. It looks like packing unreferenced assemblies in Tools has the same effect as explicitly adding references in .nuspec as @globetrotter did. The only dlls that copied to bin/debug are referenced ones. All others are there in packages\ folder, but are not copied to bin/. Is the only way to add them using post-build event? Thanks.